# Change selection after deleting rows?

Tags: vba, excel

**Want**

```
 Loop through multiple selection areas (r = 1 to n)
   Delete rows in area r
 Next area
```

**Notes**
Selections can be non-contiguous, and can be in any (vertical) order. I.e. Area 1 could be rows 8-10, Area 2 could be rows 2-3, Area 3 could be rows 14-18. Selected cell areas should not overlap to prevent error.

**Problem**
Performing a row delete in one area results in all data below to shift up. Selected areas below do not shift. So new data (you do not want to delete) rolls into selected areas.

**Example**

```
Row 1: A B C
Row 2: D E F  (Select R2C1:R2C3 first)
Row 3: G H I
Row 4: J K L  (CTRL Select R4C1:R4C3 next)
Row 5: M N O
```

There are 2 areas selected. We wish to delete rows 2 and 4.

**Code**

```
For aCounter = 1 to Selection.Areas.Count
   Selection.Areas(aCounter).EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

**Result**

```
Row 1: A B C
Row 2: G H I  (This row is selected)
Row 3: J K L
Row 4: (blank) (This row is also selected)
Row 5: (blank)
```

**What happened**
The first area selected (Areas(1)) was row 2, which was deleted. Rows 3-5 rolled up, but Area 2 remained on row 4. This means that J K L went into row 3, and M N O went into row 4. On the next loop, Areas(2) still was set to row 4, so M N O was deleted.

**What should happen**
Areas(2) should have moved up by the number of deleted rows.

**Question**
Is there a way to code this easily without looping through all areas, checking to see if they are below the deleted row, and moving them up the number of deleted rows each time a row is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Union to delete in 1 time:(no overlapping areas)

```
Sub try()
Dim MyRng As Range

For aCounter = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
    If Not MyRng Is Nothing Then
        Set MyRng = Application.Union(MyRng, Selection.Areas(aCounter))
    Else
        Set MyRng = Selection.Areas(aCounter)
    End If
Next
MyRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

with overlapping Areas:

```
Sub try2()
Dim MyRng As Range, MyRow As Range

For aCounter = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
    If Not MyRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each MyRow In Selection.Areas(aCounter).Rows
        If Intersect(MyRow, MyRng) Is Nothing Then
        Set MyRng = Application.Union(MyRng, MyRow)
        End If
        Next MyRow
    Else
        Set MyRng = Selection.Areas(aCounter)
    End If
Next
MyRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: This works- it is irrespective of the selection order. The only time it breaks is if the selection areas overlap rows. I have written a solution which fixes this problem below.

Comment: You have clearly spent a lot of time working with ranges and merging criteria. I like this solution better than the one I posted using a non-vba standard container object, simply because your code is portable.

Comment: I have extended your solution to include multiple areas in different columns, whose rows may overlap. The module is becoming more and more error proof. I will post solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Start at the bottom and delete rows as you go up.

For example:

```
  For aCounter = Selection.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
     Selection.Areas(aCounter).EntireRow.Delete
  Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option. In the "Notes" section, I mentioned that selections can be in any order. Excel remembers the order that areas are selected and adds them to the Areas collection in that order. So you would have to first sort the areas collection, and then work from the bottom up.

Comment: Ah, I missed that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple areas are selected, and the rows of 2 or more overlap, VBA throws an overlapping error. To workaround, you must do a manual union and record the rows (being sure not to record duplicate rows).

Here is a solution which involves using the System.Collections.ArrayList container object. It is not part of the standard VBA library. If you are not planning on sharing the file, you could add a reference to \WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb or mscorlib.dll. Then the code is as follows:

```
Dim col As New Collection
Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
CreateObject ("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Dim alist As New ArrayList

For i = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
    For j = 1 To Selection.Areas(i).Rows.Count
        r = Selection.Areas(i).Rows(j).Row
        If Not alist.Contains(r) Then alist.Add r
    Next
Next

alist.Sort
alist.Reverse

For i = 0 To alist.Count - 1
    Rows(alist(i)).EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

What this does is create an ArrayList container object, then it for each area it checks if the row is already in the list. If not, it adds it.

This creates a list of rows that are in some order depending on the order the areas were selected.

The ArrayList has a built in .sort and .reverse method, as well as the .contains method which also is handy.

The resultant ArrayList now contains the rows to delete in reverse order, so you just step through the list and delete. This method will work around the overlapping selection areas problem.

---

Adding to the idea from user @Evr , here is a portable module that handles the case of overlapping areas in different columns:

```
Dim myrng As Range, arng As Range, offrng As Range
Dim acounter As Long

For acounter = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
    If Not myrng Is Nothing Then
            Set arng = Selection.Areas(acounter)
            Set offrng = arng.Offset(, -arng.Columns(1).Column + 1).Resize(, 1)
            Set myrng = Application.Union(myrng, offrng)
    Else
        Set myrng = Selection.Areas(1).Offset(, -Selection.Areas(1).Columns(1).Column + 1).Resize(, 1)
    End If
Next
myrng.EntireRow.Delete
```

Here is how it works:

The first selected area is stored in myrng, but it is brought back to column A. Hence the reason for the negative column value+1. If the area was $D9:$F12, for example, we wouldn't care about the columns D through F... all that we care about is the rows 9-12. So, we offset the range. The first column is 4, so we offset -4+1 = -3. The resultant range is $A9:$F12. The resize command then brings it back to one column: $A9:$A12.

The range 'arng" is the next selected range in the Areas list. It is also moved back to column A and resized. The result is placed into offrng.

Myrng is then unioned with offrng, and the result is an array of unique row addresses in one range, which can then be deleted using .EntireRow.Delete.

Comment: The second part of this answer references previous answer by @Evr. Limitations of site functionality prevent me directly linking Evr in my reply. So I must spam the comments to include the link.